# Using Proc Compare to compare observations in columns from two different datasets

Tags: sas, dataset

I'm trying to use proc compare to compare two columns from  two different datasets. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
proc compare base=combT compare=groupT out=results allobs listobs; 
    var comb_Var ;
    with descr;
run;
```

The issue it is saying there is nothing in common between the two columns, while I can see there are some common observation between the two columns. Any guidance will be helpful.

I'm using SAS EG and the observations in both columns are char type.

Comment: forget to mention that both columns do not have equal observations, but there is no duplicates

Comment: Can you show your log from running PROC COMPARE (with the PROC COMPARE code and all the messages after it)?  Is there an ID statement in your real code?  It's unusual to get that message, without an ID statement.  Without an ID statement, there isn't a concept of "common observations."  I do get a "WARNING: No matching observations were found." when I PROC COMPARE a dataset with 0 obs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have my log anymore. I found a work around that does not use proc compare.